# Is there a regex quantifier that says "either x or y repeats"?

Tags: regex

I want to match a string **containing only numbers with either exactly 7 digits or exactly 9 digits**.

```
/^\d{7}$|^\d{9}$/
```

Is there another way to write this, similar to `/\d{7,8}/` for 7 or 8 digits?

Comment: Your title seems to suggest that a number of 10 digits also constitutes a valid match...does it?

Comment: @VanDarg: Why would it matter in this case?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I should have said "exactly (7 or 9) digits".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
/^\d{7}(?:\d{2})?$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of string
\d{7}  # Match 7 digits
(?:    # Try to match...
 \d{2} #  2 digits
)?     # ...optionally
$      # End of string
```

Comment: I'm curious about the order of operations. Does the following work as well? `/^\d{7}\d{2}?$/`

Comment: No, you can't quantify quantifiers. A `?` after a `{...}` would make the `{...}` quantifier *lazy*, which doesn't make sense if there is only one possible value. (Think `x{1,5}?` which would match 1 to 5 `x`es, but try to match as few as possible.)

Comment: I like this one best because of the `(:?)` no-capture group. Thank you, and also thanks to all the others.

Comment: Thanks! The `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, correct? In the past I've preferred these for performance reasons any time I'm not planning to use the specific capture. (Correct me if I've stated anything wrong here.)

Comment: This does not work. I ran this pattern with https://regexr.com/ and input of a few numbers with exactly 7, 8, 9, etc. digits, no one was matched. Also with Rusts regex crate it does not work.

Comment: @ThomasPiekarski: Did you remove the `/` delimiters before pasting the regex into regexr?

Comment: @Tim Pietcker Yes, I removed them. But regexr auto-detects these and it auto-removes them. Does this regexp work for you in regexr?

Comment: @ThomasPiekarski: Yes. Of course, if your test string contains more than a single line, you need to set the `/gm` flags to allow multiple matches and to change the behavior of the `^$` anchors.

Answer (score 5):

Alternation alternative:

```
/^(\d{7}|\d{9})$/
```

Comment: This is probably the clearest expression of exactly what the OP requested, even though I personally lean towards left factoring the expression as others have done.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regular expression

```
^\d{7}(\d{2})?$
```

Answer (score 2):

Match 7 digits, then match an optional two digits.

```
/^\d{7}(\d{2})?/
```